# An expression that's equivalent to the return keyword

Tags: c#

```
void Foo()
{
    var xMaybeNull = GetX();
    if (xMabyeNull == null) return; // Some way to get rid of this extra
                                    // sentence without loosing the check
    // do stuff
}
```

The easy way would be this, but the compiler expects an expression.

```
void Foo()
{
    List<Disc[,]> xNeverNull = GetX() ?? return;
    // do stuff
}
```

The question is, is there any way to write the `someSortOfReturnExpression` (I guess not) or another solution, that can do what I'm looking for on one line?

```
void Foo()
{
    List<Disc[,]> xNeverNull = GetX() ?? someSortOfReturnExpression;
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: What you have know is perfectly clear, readable and succinct. There's no need to obscure it.

Comment: I see this pattern all over the place.  However, if you want to nitpick the first option for style reasons, consider adding curly braces around the return and putting the constant on the left-hand-side of the == operator (to avoid unintentional assignment, which is a problem in some languages).  It would look like: if (null == xMabyeNull) { return; }

Comment: Everyone knows that code is better if it fits on one line. It runs quicker too.

Comment: @David: You can't say that code size is the same as code speed. Especially considering the amount of optimization that compilers do these days, as well as the fact that .Net utilizes a JIT. I also don't (i.e. *won't*) accept the "one-line is better" argument.

Comment: There is also no inherent reason that one line of C# source results in less MSIL than two lines of source -- it is *compiled*, after all, and there are many counter-cases. The most trivial may be `int x; x = 1;` and `int x = 1;`.

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLine: Your sarcasm detector failed.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, I realized that about ten minutes after I wrote it - 'tis a veeery slow day for me.

Comment: @jason @ken @pst I guess I just got a bit tired of all the questions based on the false assumptions that I lampooned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as envisioned in C# because of the non-"functional syntax". (Please see notes at very bottom). While the conditional operator (`?:`) can be used in some trivial places, it very quickly runs into limits. And, as others have pointed out, the coalesce operator (`??`) which carries forward the expression, doesn't support an "else" case. Thus C# functions must use conventions to achieve similar semantics. The following discusses my approach to this problem.

--

With very few exceptions, *I do not use early returns from functions*. While C# doesn't have a "functional syntax", I still find the style of code which reads from start of a function to the end of a function most clear -- that is, only the *last statement* of the *last level of branches* (possibly nested) can return from a function, just as though the conditional itself (`if/else if/else`) was an expression (like `?:`) that `return`ed a value. (If there are too many branches, it may be a sign the function is too large.)

In most cases I would write the code as the following:

```
void Foo()
{
    var xMaybeNull = GetX();  
    if (xMabyeNull != null) {
        // Know it's valid to use xMaybeNull in here -- can't be null.
        // "do stuff"
    }
    // xMaybeNull may be null here. So don't put anything here
    // that requires otherwise. In this case the flow will just "drop off"
    // so the `return` is completely omitted.
}
```

Since I follow this pattern consistently it helps me read/understand my code and flow better. This approach also avoids "being too tricky" and is very easily to extend to handle the "null case" by just adding the `else` to the end. Keeping the assignment first and *separate* keeps the code simpler and allows the use of `var`, which I find very nice.

Happy coding.

---

The one case where I do push up the condition and an early function exit is with raised *exceptions* in guards...

```
if (argX == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("argX");
```

...but such is the nature of exceptions.

---

Actually, this *can* be done with Extension Methods in a manner similar to SmallTalk. However, in this case, it would just introduce more complications. Don't keep the Cleverness Goggles on too long. Imagine:

```
public static void IfNotNull<T>(this T it, Action<T> action) {
    if (it != null) action(it);
}

GetX().IfNotNull((x) => {
    // "do stuff", x can't be null
});
```

Comment: Wow it can be done! Thanks alot for the great answer. 
I'll stick to the simple if check like you and jglouie suggested to keep it all simple and easy to read though. But i'll never forget the alternative :-)

Answer (score 8):

What's wrong with the first option?

I'd personally stick with that option.  It's readable, common, and very understandable by others who may end up maintaining your code.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if GetX() happens to be null -- and it's an exceptional case here when it is null -- throw an exception to alert the caller instead of hiding it.

Comment: i'd stick to this any day of the week as well for the exact reasons you have provided. +1

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The `??` operator means 'give me the first argument if it is not null, otherwise the second argument. You can't use it for flow control.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rest of the method, would an empty list have no effect on the rest of your class? If so, you could just use:

```
List<Disc[,]> xNeverNull = GetX() ?? new List<Disc[,]>();
```

Although the List class is based on Arrays, which afair initializes with a small array to begin with, so there could be some memory penalty. If you dont have to modify the list, or you don't need an indexer, you might consider:

```
IEnumerable<Disc[,]> xNeverNull = GetX() ?? System.Linq.Enumerable.Empty<Disc[,]>();
```

or

```
ICollection<Disc[,]> xNeverNull = GetX() ?? new LinkedList<Disc[,]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
void Foo()
{
    List<Disc[,]> xNeverNull;
    if (null != (xNeverNull = GetX())
    {
    // do the stuff here
    }
}
```